# ERROR: AddressSanitizer failed to deallocate

Tags: memory-management, llvm, address-sanitizer, fuzzing

I am fuzzing using a harness.

Get this error in my fuzzer

```
==1303173==ERROR: AddressSanitizer failed to deallocate 0x43000 (274432) bytes at address 0x7ffb83969000
==1303173==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: /build/llvm-toolchain-9-uSl4bC/llvm-toolchain-9-9/projects/compiler-rt/lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_posix.cc:61 "(("unable to unmap" && 0)) != (0)" (0x0, 0x0)
==1303173==ERROR: AddressSanitizer failed to deallocate 0xcf000 (847872) bytes at address 0x7ffb80300000
==1303173==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: /build/llvm-toolchain-9-uSl4bC/llvm-toolchain-9-9/projects/compiler-rt/lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_posix.cc:61 "(("unable to unmap" && 0)) != (0)" (0x0, 0x0)
```

Any idea why it can happen each time after ca. 12 hours of fuzzing? What could be the reasons? It is deallocation, should be not relevant, but free mem seems to be also there.

Thanks,

Comment: this needs to be more concise to help. what's the program? what's the fuzzer? what's the seed? I'm not surprised something like that happens after 12h

Comment: @dv3 isn't this weird that ASan cannot dealocate its own allocations? I am using LibAFL.... Switched now to AFL++. I think this was LibAFL related. Would be cool to catch the testcase causing it with LibAFL, maybe it is some corruption. I would not assume ASan, as I said, cannot deallocate its own allocations. Don't have that much experience with ASan though. Unless this is totally normal

Comment: Thinking to maybe modify LLVM to send SIGSEGV in the check to catch the testcase, to see if this is it or more complex issue

Comment: Child exited with code 256. So I try to catch signal 128 and raise SIGSEGV using LD_PRELOAD in fuzzer harness. Maybe will catch the testcase

Comment: Nah ... need to recompile ASan and change this: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/69445f095c22aac2388f939bedebf224a6efcdaf/lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_linux.cpp#L426 to abort() or raise(SIGSEGV)

Comment: I see you're getting help on the fuzzing discord - these folks can help you better than I ever could... so just make sure you post the solution here in the end :)